# height del ng-repeat es zero

Tags: angularjs

por que sale 0 cero de tamaño en altura del div con id="box2"?

**el tamano deberia ser la sumatoria de todos los items del json**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    var box1=document.getElementById("box1");
  var box2=document.getElementById("box2");

  
  console.log(box1.getBoundingClientRect().height);
   console.log(box2.getBoundingClientRect().height);
 
  $scope.records = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "mia"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "juan"
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: "juan"
  }];
  

});
```

```css
#box1 {
     width: 150px;
     height: 25px;
}

#box2{
height: 50px;
display: block;
}


.visible{
overflow:scroll;
}

.ocultar{
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#cd{
height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="box1">
      <div id="box2">
        <div id="cd" ng-repeat="x in records">
          <div>{{x.id}}.- {{x.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El metodo height coloca 0 por defecto en tu consola al no tener definida una altura en tu etiqueta `<div id="box2">`

```
#box2{
height: 50px;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: deberia ser la sumatoria de todos los items del json, ahora 50px es fijo, deberia ser dinamico

Comment: @hubman que pretendes hacer amigo? sabes para que sirve esta función getBoundingClientRect()?

Comment: quiero obtener el tam del ng-repeat solo eso

Comment: ok hubman, lo revisare y te estaré comentando.